# Issue when using GROUP BY a date(datetime field) and HAVING in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm currently facing an issue with an SQL query involving the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses. I am attempting to group results by date(SALE_CREATION_DATETIME) or CAST(SALE_CREATION_DATETIME AS DATE)  while filtering based on certain conditions. However, I am experiencing difficulties and unable to achieve the expected result.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(T.SALE_CREATION_DATETIME) AS CREATION_DATE,
  count(), sum(), ...,
  T.ClientFlag AS CLIENT_FLAG,
  T.CampaignFlag AS CAMPAIGN_FLAG, 
  CASE WHEN ... THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE
  END AS TASK_FLAG,...
FROM
  `my_project.dataset.TABLE_TASK` AS T
LEFT JOIN
  `my_project.dataset.TABLE_USER` AS U
ON
  T.OwnerId = U.Id
LEFT JOIN
  `my_project.dataset.TABLE_CONVERSIONS` AS TC
ON
  T.Id = TC.EVENT_ID
GROUP BY 
  DATE(T.SALE_CREATION_DATETIME),
  T.ClientFlag,
  T.CampaignFlag,
     ...
  HAVING TASK_FLAG is TRUE
```

ERROR in BIGQUERY:

> SELECT list expression references T.SALE_CREATION_DATETIME which is
> neither grouped nor aggregated

PS: I have to group by DATE() and not the field itself to avoid duplicates.

Is the issue related to the grouping or the HAVING field? I'm receiving unexpected results, and I suspect the problem may be in how I'm using GROUP BY with the HAVING condition. Could someone take a look and help me to structure this query?

Comment: You probably have `T.SALE_CREATION_DATETIME` in your select clause (which you've replaced with `...` in the question).

Comment: Is `TASK_FLAG` derived from aggregate data?

Comment: @SalmanA no I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the DATE() wrap in the GROUP BY clause so you should be able to use:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(T.SALE_CREATION_DATETIME) AS CREATION_DATE,
  count(), sum(), ...,
  T.ClientFlag AS CLIENT_FLAG,
  T.CampaignFlag AS CAMPAIGN_FLAG, 
  CASE WHEN ... THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE
  END AS TASK_FLAG,...
FROM
  `my_project.dataset.TABLE_TASK` AS T
LEFT JOIN
  `my_project.dataset.TABLE_USER` AS U
ON
  T.OwnerId = U.Id
LEFT JOIN
  `my_project.dataset.TABLE_CONVERSIONS` AS TC
ON
  T.Id = TC.EVENT_ID
GROUP BY 
  T.SALE_CREATION_DATETIME,
  T.ClientFlag,
  T.CampaignFlag,
     ...
  HAVING TASK_FLAG is TRUE
```

Comment: That's not the same thing, because it doesn't group by day, only by the date and time together.

Comment: I would encounter duplicates due to the presence of identical "date" entries occurring multiple times, as the datetime values associated with them are not uniform.

Comment: I think BigQuery can handle aliasing in the GROUP BY so perhaps try 'GROUP BY CREATION_DATE...'. Failing that, you could also try referencing the column indexes i.e. 'GROUP BY 1, <field number of T.ClientFlag>, <field number of T.CampaignFlag>,...'.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution I devised for my issue involves utilizing aliases in place of fields. Instead of employing DATE(T.SALE_CREATION_DATETIME), I opt for grouping by CREATION_DATE.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first field in the `SELECT` is deriving `DATE` and aliasing it, and the `GROUP BY` isn’t happy, use `GROUP BY 1, …` instead.
The 1 replaces both the DATE(…) conversion and the alias.

When using a derived field in `GROUP BY` in BigQuery, using the field position number gets around it all.

You can’t group by the field’s alias (in this case `CREATION_DATE`) as the field doesn’t exist yet.
You can use the alias in `HAVING` as by the time that gets executed, the field exists with the alias.